# Continuous deployment for single sql script

Tags: azure-devops

I am facing issue with single script deployment. How to setup SQL script file for build pipeline and release pipeline in Azure DevOps.

[image]

What will be the exact path of the SQL file. If I give C:\test\test.sql, it says invalid path.

Comment: Don't know what this task is that you're using, but I'm quite sure your files are not in c:\test unless you've manually downloaded them there and then you would know the dir. Most likely you need to prefix it with the artifact dir variable or something similar. You can create a batch task to use `dir`, `set` etc. to see files, variables etc. Also refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

Agree with James. It looks like you didn't specify the correct path. You can write a command with `dir` to list the files under the specific path you specified to see if the `sql` files are there. Then troubleshoot further.

Sine you are using classic release pipeline. You can use the predefined [Classic release and artifacts variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch).

Basically, we can set the location of the SQL script file on the automation agent or on a UNC path accessible to the automation agent like, `\\BudgetIT\Web\Deploy\xx.sql`. Predefined system variables like, `$(agent.releaseDirectory)` or `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)` can also be used here.

By default, artifacts are downloaded to `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)` during deployment of a release. And the real path should be like this : `C:\agent\_work\r1\a`